# Return URL in POST-method when working with base64ImageField and nested serializers

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, base64

First of all, I'm pretty new to Django and equally new to backend development so please go easy on me.

I'm setting up a backend for a mobile application in which a user should be able to post an advert with an image attached to it over Http Requests. Right now, this works like it should, a user sends a POST request containing all the needed information and gets a response back containing all the relevant information, except for the image which is *null*. I know that the image successfully gets uploaded to the server, however I can't figure out how to return the URL of the image back into the response.

The following is my code:

***models.py***

```
class Advert(models.Model):

    owner=models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="adverts")
    book_title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    price = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=now())

    def __str__(self):
        return self.book_title + ' - ' + self.contact_info


class AdvertImage(models.Model):
    advert = models.ForeignKey(Advert, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="image", null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'ad_images', null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.image.name
```

My serializers looks as following:

***serializers.py***

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Advert, AdvertImage
from drf_extra_fields.fields import Base64ImageField
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class AdvertPostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    image =  Base64ImageField(max_length=None, use_url=True, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Advert
        fields = (
        'id',
        'price',
        'book_title',
        'image')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        try:
            image_data = validated_data.pop('image')
        except:
            image_data = None
        advert = Advert.objects.create(**validated_data)
        if image_data is not None:
            image = AdvertImage.objects.create(advert=advert, image=image_data)

        return advert
```

And this is my view:

***views.py***

```
class AdvertViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Advert.objects.all()
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.action == 'create':
            return AdvertPostSerializer
        return AdvertSerializer

    @action(methods=['get'], detail=False)
    def newest(self,request):
        newest = self.get_queryset().order_by('created_at').last()
        serializer = self.get_serializer_class()(newest)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        return serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)
```

To illustrate what happens, here is a POST request:

```
POST http://localhost:8000/post-advert/ 
"Authorization: Token 980436128332ce3" 
book_title=my book 
price=1000
image=data:image/png;base64,iVBORHJvZmlsZSB0e//+egAAAAASUVORK5CYII=
```

And this is the response:

```
{
    "book_title": "my book",
    "id": 45,
    "image": null,
    "price": 1000,
}
```

Looking in the database and sending a second GET-request to another view shows that everything is uploaded as it should and the foreign keys and whatnot works like they should, it's just that I have a really hard time figuring out how to send back the URL of the image as a response to a successful POST.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright so I managed to come up with a (hacky?) solution.

In serializers.py i put my Base64Field as read_only=True:

```
class AdvertPostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    image =  Base64ImageField(max_length=None, use_url=True, required=False, read_only=True)
    ...
```

Then, in my views.py for my AdvertViewSet, I've overwritten my create() method as such:

```
def create(self, request, format='json'):
        serializer = PostAdvertSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            advert = serializer.save()
            if advert:
                json = serializer.data
                advertImageURL = AdvertImage.objects.get(advert=advert).image.url
                json['img_link'] = request.build_absolute_uri(advertImageURL)
                return Response(json, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

And this returns the full path to my image!

Answer (score 0):

Because your get_queryset() method in

```
 newest = self.get_queryset().order_by('created_at').last()
```

returns **Advert** model object:

```
class AdvertViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Advert.objects.all()
```

which do not have image field. Then you are creating **AdvertPostSerializer** object and initializing it with **newest** queryset which is queryset of **Advert** model without your **image**.

```
serializer = self.get_serializer_class()(newest)
```

You can somehow obtain **AdvertImage** object inside **@newest action** and try to add it to response, but think you can create only one model **Advert** with your **image** field and one serializer for it, where you will define **Base64ImageField**.

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to respond. Even if I comment the "newest" codeblock out, nothing really changes when making POST-requests to my adverts. The adverts register as usual and image still returns null. I understand that this has to do with returning the advert which does not contain a image field, however I don't know how to still get it to return the URL.